# Second derivative of a function $\frac{\sin x}{(1+a \cos x)}$

Tags: derivatives

Let 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{(1+a \cos x)}
\end{equation}
Where $a > 0$ is a constant.
I found that 
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = \frac{a + \cos x}{ (1+a \cos x)^2}
\end{equation}
and for the second derivative

\begin{equation}
f''(x) =  (2a^2-1)\sin x +  (2a^3-4a)\sin x \cos x -  (a^2+2a^2)\sin x \cos^2 x
\end{equation}
I am not sure if my derivative functions are right.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Your second derivative is wrong. Just apply the same method to find $f''(x)$ from $f'(x)$ as you did to find $f'(x)$ from your $f(x)$ (either the quotient or product rule).

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative is correct, but for the second derivative I've found $$f''(x) = \frac{\sin(x)\left(2a^2 -1 + a \cos(x)\right)}{\left(1+a \cos(x)\right)^3}.$$

**Hint:** Use the quotient and chain rules.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to get the second derivative of $f.$  you have 
$$f^\prime = \dfrac{a+\cos x}{(a \cos x + 1)^2} = \dfrac{1/a(a \cos x + 1) + (a - 1/a)}{(a \cos x + 1)^2} = \dfrac{1}{a}(a \cos x + 1)^{-1} + (a - \dfrac{1}{a})(a \cos x + 1)^{-2}$$ so

$$f^{\prime \prime} =  \dfrac{1}{a}a \sin x (a \cos x + 1)^{-2} + 2(a - \dfrac{1}{a})a\sin x(a \cos x + 1)^{-3} = \dfrac{\sin x}{(a \cos x + 1)^2} +
\dfrac{2(a^2 - 1)\sin x}{(a \cos x + 1)^3}  $$